# Restlet how to decode secret in HTTP basic authentication

Tags: java, rest, base64, jax-rs, restlet

I have the following class handling one of my routes:

```
public class HotelsSrv extends ServerResource implements 
   HotelsListResource {
   private String hotelId;

   @Override
   protected void doInit() throws ResourceException {
       super.doInit();
       String str;
       String secret = getRequest().getChallengeResponse().getSecret().toString();
       byte[] bytes = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(secret)
       str = new String(bytes);

       System.out.println("user: "+getRequest().getChallengeResponse().getIdentifier());

       System.out.println("password: "+str);
}
```

I am trying to decode the secret so I can verify it using custom procedure but this line raises unknown exception:

```
    byte[] bytes = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(secret)
```

Comment: Did you try the code below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
public void authenticate(HttpServletRequest req) {
    String authhead = req.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (authhead != null) {
            // *****Decode the authorisation String*****
            byte[] e = Base64.decode(authhead.substring(6));
            String usernpass = new String(e);
            // *****Split the username from the password*****
            String user = usernpass.substring(0, usernpass.indexOf(":"));
            String password = usernpass.substring(usernpass.indexOf(":") + 1);
            // check username and password
        }
}
```

Comment: I did little tweak for the code above and it worked like charm:

    Series headers = HttpRequest.getCurrent().getHeaders();
        String auth = headers.getFirstValue("Authorization");

        if (auth != null) {
            // Decode  authorisation String
            byte[] e = Base64.decode(auth.substring(6));
            String usernpass = new String(e);
            // Split  username from password
            user = usernpass.substring(0, usernpass.indexOf(":"));
            password = usernpass.substring(usernpass.indexOf(":") + 1);

        }

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to encode/decode the secret. It is stored as a table of char in the ChallengeResponse class, only for security reasons (cf javadocs, and this link for more explanations http://www.careercup.com/question?id=14955419)

```
String secret = new String(getRequest().getChallengeResponse().getSecret());
```